# Listen for tray message removal in Java

Tags: java, system-tray

I've created a notification system using SystemTray. The program has a notification queue, these notifications should be displayed 1 by 1. Next notification should be shown only after the previous one has disappeared/faded away from the screen.

Is there any way to detect when a tray message completely fades away?